# How can I determine that the value of column1 in df1 contains in column1 in df2 starting strictly from the left (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'number': ['14578', '45621', '1564']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'number': ['1457891521', '123456215', '15643']})
```

My question how is it possible to determine if df1['number'] contains in df2['number'] strictly from the left.

Desirable result:

```
number  full number
0   14578   1457891521
1   45621   0
2   1564    15643
```

Comment: So can the DataFrames be of different size? Do you want to match the corresponding value in each DataFrame or any of the values of the other dataframe?

Comment: Yes df can be different sizes. I want to match the value from df1 to values from df2. So for example df1 can be smaller size than df2

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately need to loop here:

```
df1['full number'] = [b if b.startswith(a) else ''
                      for a,b in zip(df1['number'], df2['number'])]
```

Output:

```
  number full number
0  14578  1457891521
1  45621            
2   1564       15643
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using `numpy`, specifically [`numpy.char.startswith`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.startswith.html):

```
x2, x1 = df2['number'].values.astype(str), df1['number'].values.astype(str)
out = df1
out['full number'] = df2.loc[np.char.startswith(x2, x1), 'number']
```

Output:

```
  number full number
0  14578  1457891521
1  45621         NaN
2   1564       15643
```